# HDMI over cat extender video

Tags: hdmi, video-streaming

when using an HDMI over cat extender, does it consider a screen of 16 parallel streams (security cameras) as one stream or do I have to make sure it's compatible with 16 streams, basically by the time it gets to the extender is it one stream or did the server processor already encoded it in one stream? also if it's considered multiple streams would using a weak one cause flickering? any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2):

HDMI doesn't support multiple separate streams over a single HDMI port/cable. So if you have some kind of NVR box that shows you all your camera feeds on one HDMI output, it has already downsampled and composited all your camera feeds into a single video stream.

This has nothing to do with whether or not you use adapters to send that HDMI feed over UTP cable.